# Turning off Git's https verification

Tags: git

I am testing an internal git repository hosted with a self-signed Apache cert.

Unfortunately, I can't manage to push to it without an error like so

> error: gnutls_handshake() failed: A TLS warning alert has been received. while accessing https://*url*

I have performed the following settings:

in .git/config

```
[http]
    sslverify = false
```

And in the environment variable world:

```
declare -x CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST="0"
declare -x GIT_CURL_VERBOSE="1"
declare -x GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY="true"
```

What else might be my problem?

Answer (score 3):

Just as a reference for people having the same problem: it's very likely that this happens due to git using libcurl-gnutls3 version < 7.21.7 on old Debian and Ubuntu distros.

There was a bug in the library that made it misbehave at least when going through an HTTP proxy  to reach a HTTPS website (either your own local proxy or a remote reverse proxy or a government's transparent proxy). The question doesn't state if the author was using a proxy or not but I strongly suspect the problem could be related if not the same. See https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=559371

The fix is to either upgrade to a new distro that supports a fixed libcurl-gnutls3 version, rebuild it yourself, rebuild git to use libcurl-openssl (see https://askubuntu.com/questions/186847/error-gnutls-handshake-falied ) or... avoid using https

Comment: I believe this is not limited to the user using a proxy: I've got this error recently where I had no proxy configured on my machine, however the git "server" I was connecting to was in reality a reverse proxy to the real git server.

Comment: You're right: I said "going though a proxy" but the answer could use being more explicit

Answer (score 1):

It could be that ServerName in your apache VirtualHost is not right. It should correspond to the certificate server name. To find out the reason of TLS alert I suggest running wireshark.

Comment: And if the server name is not configured right in the apache virtualhost, then openssl reports no errors, but gnutls reports an error (and a particularly uninformative one at that).

Answer (score 0):

Make git use the HTTPS instead:

Assuming your self-signed certificate is:

```
/etc/ssl/certs/selfsigned.pem
```

Do the following:

```
openssl x509 -in /etc/ssl/certs/selfsigned.pem -out ~/certs/selfsigned.crt
git config --global http.sslcainfo ~/certs/selfsigned.crt
```

Comment: Interesting. That doesn't work.  I am relatively sure that this problem is compounded by the proxy. Do you know how to ensure Git (& libcurl) does not access a proxy?

Comment: To turn of the proxy for git:
`git config core.gitproxy '"none" for example.com'`
Example.com would your internal domain name.
If you want git to default to no proxy, for all domains `git config core.gitproxy none`

Comment: I got the proxy turned off, happily. However, the SSL verification disabling doesn't work, for reasons obscure to me, but possibly related to how git is built on launchpad & static/dynamic linking. I've narrowed the question down to turning off ssl verification.

Comment: Where on the client side are the SSL certs installed? Copy your servers cert to that directory and see what happens.

Comment: (1) it doesn't work. I've tried. (2), I really want to solve my *stated* problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem. After populating the servername in apache config for virtualhost, this worked. while curl --cacert https..var.git works, git clone https:..var.git threw the error -

> Cloning into 'var'...
>       error: gnutls_handshake() failed: A TLS warning alert has been received. while accessing https://foo.server/var.git/info/refs
>       fatal: HTTP request failed

one more thing you should do, is after you do

> cd /var/www/var (var is the document root)
>
> ```
> sudo git clone --bare ~foo/var
> sudo git update-server-info
> ```

Comment: n.b.; this problem is long-gone to me. I've moved on. Hope your advice helps others!